# What's wrong with my implementation of Flurl?

Tags: c#, api, flurl

I'm using Flurl to query an API and I'm experiencing some very odd behaviour.

```
namespace StravaAPI
{
    public class StravaAPI
    {
        public StravaAPI()
        {
            _Client = new FlurlClient().WithOAuthBearerToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        }

        private FlurlClient _Client;

        private const string BASE_URL = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3";
        // This is my access token, should be replaced by the access token of the logged in and authenticated user
        private const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "#####removed for privacy####";

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a summary representation of an athlete
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">The id of the required athlete</param>
        /// <returns>A summary representation of the athlete even if the indicated athlete matches the authenticated athlete.</returns>
        public async Task<AthleteSummary> GetAthleteSummary(int id)
        {
            var url = $"{BASE_URL}/athletes/{id}";
            return await GetData<AthleteSummary>(url);
        }

        public async Task<Athlete> GetCurrentAthlete()
        {
            var url = $"{BASE_URL}/athlete/";
            return await GetData<Athlete>(url);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetData<T>(string url) where T : IData
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending request to {url}");
            T data = await _Client.WithUrl(url).GetJsonAsync<T>();
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Calls to GetAthleteSummary are successful, but calls to GetCurrentAthlete are returned with a 401 Unauthorized.

If I use an alternative method of passing the access token, as a query parameter in the GET request rather than as a header, calls to GetCurrentAthlete are successful.

The above led me to believe that it must be an issue with the API, but I've used Fiddler to send a request to the URL, including the "Authorization" header with the value "Bearer ####removed for privacy####" and this is successful.

So the issue doesn't look to be with Flurl, as it sends requests via the GetAthleteSummary method correctly. It doesn't look to be with with the API, as it responds correctly to a request via Fiddler. So it must be that I'm doing something wrong...but I don't know what!

The following are example requests from the docs of the API I'm using:

```
$ curl -G https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer 83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9"

$ curl -G https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/227615 \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer 83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9"
```

Please help!

If any more information is required, just let me know. I appreciate that, if anyone is going to try and run this code to debug it, you'll need my access token. Anyone wanting it is free to contact me privately and I'll pass it over.

Cheers.

Edit:

Full example console application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl.Http;

namespace SOExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var api = new StravaAPI();
            var summaryUser = api.GetAthleteSummary().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {summaryUser.FirstName}");
            Athlete currentUser = new Athlete();
            try
            {
                currentUser = api.GetCurrentAthlete().Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {currentUser.FirstName}");
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            var stats = api.GetCurrentAthleteStats().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"This year you have done {stats.Ytd_Run_Totals.Count} runs covering {stats.Ytd_Run_Totals.Distance} metres!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public class StravaAPI
        {
            public StravaAPI()
            {
                _Client = new FlurlClient().WithOAuthBearerToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            }

            private FlurlClient _Client;

            private const string BASE_URL = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3";
            // This is my access token, should be replaced by the access token of the logged in and authenticated user
            private const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "####removed for privacy####";
            // This is my account id, should be replaced by the ID of the logged in and authenticated user
            private const int USER_ID = ####removed for privacy####;

            /// <summary>
            /// Get a summary representation of an athlete
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="id">The id of the required athlete</param>
            /// <returns>A summary representation of the athlete even if the indicated athlete matches the authenticated athlete.</returns>
            public async Task<AthleteSummary> GetAthleteSummary(int id = USER_ID)
            {
                var url = $"{BASE_URL}/athletes/{id}";
                return await GetData<AthleteSummary>(url);
            }

            public async Task<Athlete> GetCurrentAthlete()
            {
                var url = $"{BASE_URL}/athlete/";
                return await GetData<Athlete>(url);
            }

            //TODO: Make this based on the currentAthlete rather than a supplied ID
            public async Task<Stats> GetCurrentAthleteStats(int id = USER_ID)
            {
                var url = $"{BASE_URL}/athletes/{id}/stats";
                return await GetData<Stats>(url);
            }

            public async Task<T> GetData<T>(string url) where T : IData
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Sending request to {url}");
                T data = await new FlurlClient().WithOAuthBearerToken(ACCESS_TOKEN).WithUrl(url).GetJsonAsync<T>();
                return data;
            }
        }

        public class Athlete : AthleteSummary
        {
            public int? FollowerCount { get; set; }
            public int? FriendCount { get; set; }
            public int? MutualFriendCount { get; set; }
            public AthleteType? AthleteType { get; set; }
            public string DatePreference { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// feet or metres
            /// </summary>
            public string MeasurementPreference { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public int? Ftp { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Athlete's weight in kilograms
            /// </summary>
            public double? Weight { get; set; }
            // TODO: Add these below once we have created the required classes
            // CLUBS
            // BIKES
            // SHOES
        }

        public class AthleteSummary : IData
        {
            public int? Id { get; set; }
            public ResourceState? ResourceState { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// URL to a 62x62 pixel profile picture
            /// </summary>
            public string ProfileMedium { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// URL to a 126x124 pixel profile picture
            /// </summary>
            public string Profile { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string Sex { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// pending, accepted, blocked or null - the authenticated athlete’s following status of this athlete
            /// </summary>
            public string Friend { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// pending, accepted, blocked or null - the authenticated athlete’s following status of this athlete
            /// </summary>
            public string Follower { get; set; }
            public bool? Premium { get; set; }
            public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
            public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        }

        public interface IData
        {
        }

        public class Stats : IData
        {
            public double? Biggest_Ride_Distance { get; set; }
            public double? Biggest_Climb_Elevation_Gain { get; set; }
            public Totals Recent_Ride_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals Recent_Run_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals Recent_Swim_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals Ytd_Ride_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals Ytd_Run_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals Ytd_Swim_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals All_Ride_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals All_Run_Totals { get; set; }
            public Totals All_Swim_Totals { get; set; }
        }

        public class Totals
        {
            public int? Count { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Distance in metres
            /// </summary>
            public double? Distance { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Moving time in seconds
            /// </summary>
            public int? Moving_Time { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Elapsed time in seconds
            /// </summary>
            public int? Elapsed_Time { get; set; }
            public double? Elevation_Gain { get; set; }
            public int? Achievement_Count { get; set; }
        }

        public enum AthleteType
        {
            Cyclist = 0,
            Runner = 1
        }

        public enum ResourceState
        {
            Meta = 1,
            Summary = 2,
            Detailed = 3
        }
    }
}
```

Result: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAbre.png)

Comment: Maybe that's because you dispose your _Client variable during GetData call (because you wrap it in using). It can do anything when disposed - for example clear all authentication data, and so your next call fails with 401.

Comment: @Evk I've removed the using (and updated the code in the original question) and still get the Unauthorized response.

Comment: What will happen if you won't reuse _Client variable at all, but instead will create it right in GetData? new FlurlClient().WithOAuthBearerToken(ACCESS_TOKEN).WithUrl(url).GetJsonAsync<T>()

Comment: @Evk as a further point, I did try making a call to GetCurrentAthlete as a single request (i.e. the only use of the instantiated FlurlClient) and that also returned an Unauthorized response.

Comment: @Evk I've tried your second suggestion (i.e. not using _Client but rather a new FlurlClient each time) and this still results in an Unauthorized response.

Comment: Have last suggestion still :) What if you try to use specialized library like this one: https://github.com/inexcitus/stravadotnet ?

Comment: I understand you don't want to display your access token here, but it doesn't happen to have the word "Bearer" already in it does it? Just want to rule it out.

Comment: By the way, I saw you edited your code sample. The 401 made perfect sense when you were disposing of `_Client` with the `using` statement. Since updating the code (which now looks correct), are you absolutely certain the one endpoint is succeeding and the other is returning a 401? That is indeed very odd.

Comment: @Todd Positive Todd. Happy to send you the code for you to have a look at if you want?

Comment: @evk I have used that library before and that's how I've ended up wanting to do my own!

Comment: @Todd Sorry, missed the first comment. Nope, the access token I'm using doesn't contain the word Bearer.

Comment: I think you've posted all the relevant bits. I don't know anything about Strava, but it looks like "current" athlete is the one you're authenticated as. Any chance you're authenticated as a non-"athlete"of some sort? Might want to see if they can give you any guidance.

Comment: Well I'm out of options, but should be something very simple. If only we had complete example (full - starting from console Main method) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Todd I thought of speaking to them, but then I tried Fiddler and sent a request to the same URL with the same access token and I received a response so I concluded that it can't be their issue.

Comment: @Evk I would provide all of the code but it's split out in to two projects and could get messy trying to put it all in to a question on here. Again, happy to send you the code if you want to have a look at it.

Comment: Well I believe it's not hard to pull all relevant code to a simple console application which first does GetAthleteSummary (success) followed by GetAthlette (failure). No need to include your token there, just so that you yourself ensured that this small console application reproduces your issue.

Comment: @Evk I've included a full console application (missing only the personal data) in the original question

Comment: @Evk Now added a screenshot of the output

Comment: I will take a look at this tomorrow. One last wild guess. I see in your curl and in your other (Successful) api calls you dont have slash on the end of url, except for the failing call. Could that somehow be related?

Comment: @evk we knew it would be something stupid! That's exactly it. Thanks very much for your help both of you. Can't believe I was banging my head against the wall for so long over something so small. At least I was right and it was me being an idiot not an issue with Strava or Flurl! Thanks again

Comment: Well I'd say that is issue with Strava, they should not handle it like that. But thats another story, glad that its over :)